# flutter_form_builder >=7.0.0-beta.0 <9.0.0-dev.2 and form_builder_validators ^9.0.0-dev.1, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, api, dart, mobile

**I tried to upgrade flutter to solve this problem , commands like
flutter upgrade
pub upgrade
pub clean. this is the error msg in the termainal
Resolving dependencies... (5.7s)
Because flutter_form_builder >=7.0.0-beta.0 <9.0.0-dev.2 depends on intl ^0.17.0 and form_builder_validators >=9.0.0-dev.1 depends on intl ^0.18.0, flutter_form_builder >=7.0.0-beta.0 <9.0.0-dev.2 is
incompatible with form_builder_validators >=9.0.0-dev.1.
So, because bdt depends on both flutter_form_builder >=7.0.0-beta.0 <9.0.0-dev.2 and form_builder_validators ^9.0.0-dev.1, version solving failed.  **

`version: 1.0.0+1

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.1 <3.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  #Google Fonts
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  #HTTP Client
  http: ^0.13.5
  #HIVE
  objectbox: ^1.6.2
  objectbox_flutter_libs: ^1.6.2
  #persistent_bottom_nav_bar
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^5.0.2
  #State Management : Provider
  provider: ^6.0.3
  #Storage box
  get_storage: ^2.0.3
  #Dropdwon Alert
  flutter_dropdown_alert: ^1.0.6
  #Flutter form builder
  flutter_form_builder: '>=7.0.0-beta.0 <9.0.0-dev.2'
  #Image Upload
  form_builder_image_picker: ^3.1.0
  #Validators
  form_builder_validators: '>=9.0.0-dev.1 <10.0.0'
  inspection:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/InSol-2021/inspection.git
      ref: master
#  inspection:
#    path: ../inspection/
  #Progress HUD
  blurry_modal_progress_hud: ^1.0.3
  #Profile Icon
  flutter_initicon: ^3.0.0+1
  #Map
  flutter_map: ^3.0.0
  latlong2: ^0.8.1
  #Form Bloc
  #flutter_form_bloc: ^0.30.1
  flutter_form_bloc:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/insol-dev/form_bloc.git
      path: packages/flutter_form_bloc
#  flutter_form_bloc:
#    path: ../form_bloc/packages/flutter_form_bloc/
  #Internet Checker
  internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
  #Image_-Viewer
  easy_image_viewer: ^1.2.0
  #SVG
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  #path_provider
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  #Image Picker
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  #GeoLocator for location
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  #Pull to refresh
  pull_to_refresh_flutter3: ^2.0.1
  #File mime
  mime: ^1.0.2
  #HTTP parser
  http_parser: ^4.0.2
  #Flutter map plugin
  flutter_map_marker_popup: ^4.0.0
  #Custom Dropdown
  dropdown_button2: ^1.9.1
  #Expandable
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  #Keyboard Visibility
  flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^5.4.0
  #multi-select-list
  flutter_multi_select_items: ^0.4.2
  #responsive sizes
  sizer: ^2.0.15

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.3.0
  objectbox_generator: any
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
    

  
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Please replace with this file and make a build.

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.1 <3.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  #Google Fonts
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  #HTTP Client
  http: ^0.13.5
  #HIVE
  objectbox: ^1.6.2
  objectbox_flutter_libs: ^1.6.2
  #persistent_bottom_nav_bar
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^5.0.2
  #State Management : Provider
  provider: ^6.0.3
  #Storage box
  get_storage: ^2.0.3
  #Dropdwon Alert
  flutter_dropdown_alert: ^1.0.6
  #Flutter form builder
  flutter_form_builder: ^9.0.0
  #Image Upload
  form_builder_image_picker: ^3.1.0
  #Validators
  form_builder_validators: ^9.0.0
  inspection:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/InSol-2021/inspection.git
      ref: master
#  inspection:
#    path: ../inspection/
  #Progress HUD
  blurry_modal_progress_hud: ^1.0.3
  #Profile Icon
  flutter_initicon: ^3.0.0+1
  #Map
  flutter_map: ^3.0.0
  latlong2: ^0.8.1
  #Form Bloc
  #flutter_form_bloc: ^0.30.1
  flutter_form_bloc:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/insol-dev/form_bloc.git
      path: packages/flutter_form_bloc
#  flutter_form_bloc:
#    path: ../form_bloc/packages/flutter_form_bloc/
  #Internet Checker
  internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
  #Image_-Viewer
  easy_image_viewer: ^1.2.0
  #SVG
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  #path_provider
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  #Image Picker
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  #GeoLocator for location
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  #Pull to refresh
  pull_to_refresh_flutter3: ^2.0.1
  #File mime
  mime: ^1.0.2
  #HTTP parser
  http_parser: ^4.0.2
  #Flutter map plugin
  flutter_map_marker_popup: ^4.0.0
  #Custom Dropdown
  dropdown_button2: ^1.9.1
  #Expandable
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  #Keyboard Visibility
  flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^5.4.0
  #multi-select-list
  flutter_multi_select_items: ^0.4.2
  #responsive sizes
  sizer: ^2.0.15

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.3.0
  objectbox_generator: any
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
    

  
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
```

Comment: can you mention where you made some changes??

Comment: form builder version and form validator bersion

Comment: have build project  ?